# How can i Refresh a object?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a property representing an actor

```
private Actor _actor;

public Actor Actor
{
    get => _actor;
    set
    {
        if (_actor != value) {
            _actor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Actor");
        }   
    }
}
```

and a list, with a checkmark that depends on the state of `Actor`. When I click over the label the state of `Actor` shall change the checkmark

```
private async void OnSelectionAsync(object item)
{
    Actor = item;
```

but I cannot see the changes in my `ListView`, why?

Edit 1:

in my list, i am binding the actor Text="{Binding Actor.id} to send my converter and to change the item check

```
<Label IsVisible="False" x:Name="dTd" Text="{Binding Actor.id}" />

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Actors}">
    ...
    <Image Source="" IsVisible="{Binding id , Converter={StaticResource MyList}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference dTd}}"/>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.  You are describing actions but not showing the code that does them, so it is impossible for us to say what you might be doing wrong.  It is also unclear what the relation between Actor and Category is, or what property is supposed to drive the value of the Checkbox control.

Comment: Could you post the part in your `ResourceDictionary` where you define your Converter resource **and** the code of the converter? I believe that your issue is rooted somewhere there.

Comment: @PaulKertscher but when i refresh my list the changes i can  see them

Comment: @mikkylekyle Oh, I see.

Comment: @PaulKertscher but i dont want refresh my list, another solution?

Comment: Give me a second, already writing an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you are using the text of your label to determine whether an actor is selected or not. Anyway, you are not binding to that text in any way, but you are using the `Label` itself as a binding parameter. I do not know for sure, but it seems to me as if *"binding"* the value this way does not work as intended by you, because change notifications are not subscribed to this way. Anyway, when you refresh that list, the bindings are refreshed and the converter is used with the new value. Since `ConverterParameter` is not a bindable property I doubt that there is any chance to use it this way.

What I'd do is to either extend your `Actor` class or create a new `ActorViewModel` class with the property

```cs
public bool IsSelected
{
    get => isSelected;

    set
    {
        if (value == isSelected)
        {
            return;
        }

        isSelected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
    }
}
```

From your `ListView` you can now bind to that property

```xml
<Image Source="..." IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
```

All you have to do now is setting the property accordingly

```cs
private async void OnSelectionAsync(object item)
{
    Actor = item as Actor;
    foreach(var actor in Actors)
    {
        Actor.IsSelected = actor.id == Actor.id;
    }
}
```

this way, the change should reflect in the `ListView`.

Comment: dont refresh the listView, why?